# How to use multiple implementations of Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis with Net Core DI?

Tags: .net-core, stackexchange.redis

How do I use multiple instances of redis in net core along with the DI container?

On startup I have the following:

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
     options.Configuration = distributedCacheConnectionString;
});

services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
     options.Configuration = myAppSessionCacheConnectionString;
});
```

For injection I would have something like the following in a constructor for example:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(IDistributedCache myAppSessionCache)
        {
            // use a specific redis cache instance here
            _distributedCache = myAppSessionCache;
        }
    }
}

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyClass2
    {
        public MyClass2(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
        {
            // use a specific redis cache instance here
            _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        }
    }
}
```

I know for net core the DI container is limited compared something like Unity or Spring etc... I know for multiple implementations of an interface there are several tricks, one is injecting an IEnumerable of the interface, another example is typed interfaces, etc... I just don't see the option with the redis cache and we do have a need for an application to communicate with 2 separate redis servers within the system.

I am mostly looking for the path of least resistance. I can always create a wrapper around the Redis Client. I was just hoping that something existed but I was just overlooking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to be able to distinguish between two types of caches in your system (one for session and another for ordinary cache).

I think something like this can be done:

```
public interface ISessionDistributedCache : IDistributedCache {}

public interface IOrdinaryDistributedCache : IDistributedCache {}
```

then we have to implement these interfaces.

```
public class SessionDistributedCache : RedisCache, ISessionDistributedCache 
{
   public SessionDistributedCache(IOptions<RedisCacheOptions> optionsAccessor): base(optionsAccessor) {}
}

public class OrdinaryDistributedCache : RedisCache, IOrdinaryDistributedCache 
{
   public SessionDistributedCache(IOptions<RedisCacheOptions> optionsAccessor): base(optionsAccessor) {}
}
```

then in startup you can register these services like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISessionDistributedCache>(x =>
        {
            var options = x.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RedisCacheOptions>>();
            //options.Value.Configuration = ...  set you server IP, etc
            return new SessionDistributedCache(options);
        });
services.AddSingleton<IOrdinaryDistributedCache>(x =>
        {
            var options = x.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RedisCacheOptions>>();
            //options.Value.Configuration = ...  set you server IP, etc
            return new OrdinaryDistributedCache(options);
        });
```

Finally, you can use these two interfaces separately based on your needs.

Comment: This does work and led me into the right direction, however I did have a slight different problem in that one service extension call is in a reusable standard library that we utilize. The other redis cache setup is specific to that application. Thank you, felt like a dummy afterwards...